# Image source not updated with change in object URL - vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i wanted to show an image which comes from the server.

```
<b-img :src="previewLogo1" fluid alt=" "></b-img>
```

i am using the following to convert blob into URL on click of preview button

```
const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL
this.previewLogo1 = urlCreator.createObjectURL(res.data)
```

For the first time when we assign a value to previewLogo1 :src it is getting updated. But when ever the value changes after that, :src is not getting updated.

First time
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTAbt.png

When the value changes
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUtLo.png

URL is created each time i click preview button but not updated from second attempt.
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev4yc.png

Comment: I understood your problem but can't do anything without seeing your code. Can you add more details here(code), Including API call and response type

Comment: Hi i am getting res.data as a response to the get request.
It is a blob which is converted into url.
i am assigning it to a data property this.previewLogo1.

when i change the value of this.previewLogo1 on an event(say click) using same request :src is not getting updated.

Comment: plase let me know which part you would like to see @Naren

Comment: can you provide the `data` section of your code?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same?, not sure where you're doing mistake.